# What could cause DatePicker to render blank iframe?

Tags: datepicker, field-controls, 2007, anti-virus

I'm witnessing a strange behaviour of the DatePicker control which renders on some machines the expected table with '30 boxes'

```
<IFRAME
        style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 155px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 178px; TOP: 92px; LEFT: 225px"
        id=ctl00_m_g_d926e900_5899_46ab_94a5_e444864d0e8b_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame 
        title="Выберите дату в календаре." 
        src="/_layouts/iframe.aspx?&amp;
                cal=1&amp;
                lcid=1049&amp;
                langid=1049&amp;
                tz=03:59:59.9999513&amp;
                ww=0111110&amp;
                fdow=1&amp;
                fwoy=0&amp;
                hj=0&amp;
                swn=False&amp;
                minjday=109207&amp;
                maxjday=2666269&amp;
                date=15%2E07%2E2010" 
        frameBorder=0 
        scrolling=no 
        v4WorkSpaceDivScrollWidth="800" 
        firstUp="false" 
        leftBeforeFlip="380px">
<HTML dir=ltr>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Date Picker</TITLE>
    <META name=GENERATOR content="Microsoft SharePoint">
    <LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/_layouts/1049/styles/Themable/datepickerv4.css?rev=NGl8rHXIKyru%2F4Roim8xAw%3D%3D">
    <LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/_layouts/1049/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=NUH7%2FvckrAqUWYMSpN1KsQ%3D%3D">
    <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="./DatePicker.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="MARGIN: 0px" onkeydown=OnKeyDown(event); onload="PositionFrame('DatePickerDiv');">
    <DIV style="DISPLAY: none; DIRECTION: ltr" id=DatePickerDivM1>
        <DIV class=ms-datepickerouter>
            <DIV class=ms-quickLaunch>
                <DIV class=ms-picker-header>
                    <TABLE class=ms-picker-table border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
                        <TBODY>...</TBODY>
                    </TABLE>
                </DIV>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</IFRAME>
```

, while on others the html of the iframe.aspx does not contain the layout table for the calendar date picker.

```
<IFRAME style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 200px; DISPLAY: block; TOP: 144px"
    id=ctl00_m_g_d926e900_5899_46ab_94a5_e444864d0e8b_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateDatePickerFrame 
    title="Выберите дату в календаре." 
    src="/_layouts/iframe.aspx?&amp;
            cal=1&amp;
            lcid=1049&amp;
            langid=1049&amp;
            tz=03:59:59.9994913&amp;
            ww=0111110&amp;
            fdow=1&amp;
            fwoy=0&amp;
            hj=0&amp;
            swn=False&amp;
            minjday=109207&amp;
            maxjday=2666269&amp;
            date=" 
    frameBorder=0 
    scrolling=no 
    v4WorkSpaceDivScrollWidth="750" 
    firstUp="true" 
    leftBeforeFlip="380px">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <IMG src="http://10.0.0.44/_layouts/iframe.aspx?&amp;
                cal=1&amp;
                lcid=1049&amp;
                langid=1049&amp;
                tz=03:59:59.9994913&amp;
                ww=0111110&amp;
                fdow=1&amp;
                fwoy=0&amp;
                hj=0&amp;
                swn=False&amp;
                minjday=109207&amp;
                maxjday=2666269&amp;
                date=">
</BODY>
</HTML>
</IFRAME>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It was an issue with our corporate internet security software that blocked certain code.

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to provide a few more details on what corporate internet security was blocking the code? I have a similar issue where drop down menu's (which use iframes) are appearing blank, but only on our clients network, and only in IE8. Any help you could provide would be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: It was Kaspersky Internet Security in my case

Comment: Thanks for the response, my client is using Mcafee, but disabling it hasn't fixed the problem. :(

Comment: I finally resolved my issue - details here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/top-navigation-menu-flyouts-render-blank-iframe-in-ie8/7882#7882